# JS - Matching regex against each item of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

In js, I have this code :

```
var inputs = [];
var cijfers = /^\s*[0-9]*[1-9]+[0-9]*\s*$/;
var result = [];
inputs.push(document.getElementById("red").value,   
document.getElementById("green").value,  
document.getElementById("blue").value );
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) 
{result.push(inputs[i].match(cijfers)); console.log (result)};
```

In console, this produces three separate but identical arrays.
How can I get all matching instances in one single array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the for loop before you log the result:

```
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) 
{
    result.push(inputs[i].match(cijfers));
}
console.log(result)
```

You entered the console.log into the for loop. That's why it prints the result with one element (when i = 0). Prints two elements when i = 1. and three elements when i = 2.

Comment: Hey, this is great Alon. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.prototype.filter()`. See [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Thanks for the tip r1verside. I'll look into this first thing tomorrow.